# pg_basebackup not connecting to EC2 master instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

the following command:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h master-ip -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -U rep -v -P -x
```

is returning the following error

```
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "master-ip" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

notwithstanding the master EC2 instance has the following rule:

```
Custom TCP Rule  TCP  5432  slave-ip/32
```

and the master's /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf file includes:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32        md5
host    all             ubuntu          master-ip/32        trust
host    all             ubuntu          slave-ip/32         md5
host    all             postgres        slave-ip/32         md5
host    replication     replicator      slave-ip/32         md5
```

Both master and slave instances are EC2 instances, but created from different accounts.

What is wrong here?

Comment: It' nothing to do with `pg_hba.conf`, as it's getting that far. Check `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Here's the thing.  on the master, where 1 represents master and 2, slave,  I've got `listen_addresses = 'localhost,11.111.111.11'` as a setting that starts the server. `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` => `Connection refused Is the server running on host "stage.site.ws" (11.111.111.11) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`  The moment I add a third ip `listen_addresses = 'localhost,11.111.111.11,22.22.22.22'` the web server actually does not ever kick in and goes to a timeout.

Comment: I noticed one server did not take kindly to a comma-seperated list of addresses WITHOUT a space `localhost,22.22.22.22`, while another would. So I attempted `'localhost, 11.111.111.11, 22.22.22.22'` and the server started. But is this kosher?

Comment: Yes. The issue isn't the space, but the lack of quotes in the first one.

Comment: after various testing, the space appears to be a red herring. This ended up starting the server: `listen_addresses = 'localhost,11.111.111.11,22.22.22.22'` (it did require multiple system reboots however; `service postgresql restart` gives inconsistent behaviour FWICT).  Still, the error remains.